# Apex Class & Trigger Issue

Tags: apex, trigger, class

I am stuck on three errors that I cannot seem to diagnose in an Apex class and trigger combination.  The class is below:

```java
public class DelegatedUserSetup {
    void setObjectives(User[] users) {
        System.enqueueJob(new SetObjectivesAsQueueable(users));

     public class SetObjectivesAsQueueable implements System.Queueable{
         User[] users; 
         SetObjectivesAsQueueable(User[] users) {this.users = users;}

         void execute(System.QueueableContext qc) {
             Objectives__c[] masterObjectives = 
             [SELECT Id,Name,Duration__c,Minutes__c,OwnerId,URL__c,Week__c,Start_Date__c,Type__c 
              FROM Objectives__c WHERE MASTER__c = true];

             Objectives__c[] assignedObjectives = new List<Objectives__c>();

            for(User u : this.users){ // every user gets ea masterObjective
                for (Objective__c masterObjective : masterObjectives) {
                    assignedObjectives.add(new Objective__c (
                        OwnerId = u.Id,  // assign to user
                        Name = masterObjective.Name,
                        Status__c = 'Not started',
                        Duration__c = masterObjective.Duration__c,
                        Minutes__c = masterObjecive.Minutes__c,
                        URL__c = masterObjective.URL__c,
                        Week__c = masterObjective.Week__c,
                        Start_Date__c = masterObjective.Start_Date__c,
                        Type__c = masterObjective.Type__c,
                        MASTER__c = false
                    ));
                }
            }
             insert assignedObjectives;  // if none, no DML burnt
        }
    }
}
```

The class error is that I have an unexected token "public" on line 5
and
DelegatedUserSetup.SetObjectivesAsQueueable: Overriding implementations of global or public interface methods must be global or public: void System.Queueable.execute(System.QueueableContext)

the trigger is below:

```java
trigger insertTasks on User (after insert) {
    new DelegatedUserSetup().setObjectives(
      [SELECT Id 
        FROM User 
        WHERE Onboarding__c = TRUE AND
              Id IN: Trigger.newMap.keySet() ]
    ); // ensure only current trigger context
}
```

The error here is:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: `void setObjectives(List<User>)` from the type DelegatedUserSetup

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! In general, taking the time to make sure your indentation is consistent (in the code you post here as well as in your IDE) makes things easier to read. In some cases like this, it can also make it easy to see where the issue is. Adrian's answer is spot on, and it becomes fairly evident with proper indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't close your first method. If you want to make this method available for consumption from elsewhere, it must also be made `public`.

```
public void setObjectives(List<User> users) {
    System.enqueueJob(new SetObjectivesAsQueueable(users));
} // <-- MISSING
```

Comment: sheesh -- it was [my answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/334063/copy-task-but-change-owner-trigger/334068#334068) that had the syntax error

Comment: Oopsie! Not too late to fix. :)